# Extract values from complex list with different data types

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list whose elements are different objects - let's say strings (characters), integer, numeric and dataframes:

```
mylist <- list(letters = as.character("Hello world"), 
               numbers = as.numeric(1.254),
               table = data.frame (id = letters[1:5], value = 1:5))
```

I want to transform this list into a relational `data.table` or `data.frame`  but my R keeps throwing exceptions.

To make it even harder for me, I have a list `biglist` where each element is one of the lists like above. At the moment, this is how I am trying to achieve to put it all in a table:

```
# I start with initializing a data.table/frame result.table 
# which should then hold all the other values.
result.table <- data.table(letters = character(length(biglist), 
                           numbers = numeric(length(biglist), ... ) # and so on


for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
  result.table[i]$col1 <- mylist[[i]]$letters
  result.table[i]$col2 <- mylist[[i]]$numbers
  result.table[i]$col3 <- mylist[[i]]$table$value[1]
  result.table[i]$col4 <- mylist[[i]]$table$value[2]
}

return (result.table)
```

My R keeps telling me that something is off with the amount of columns as well as the data types as somehow they all seem to be characters (even the numbers..). Is there an idea on how I can access the values from `mylist` more efficiently and without errors?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mylist<-as.data.frame(mylist)

#       letters numbers table.id table.value
# 1 Hello world   1.254        a           1
# 2 Hello world   1.254        b           2
# 3 Hello world   1.254        c           3
# 4 Hello world   1.254        d           4
# 5 Hello world   1.254        e           5
```

Comment: Doesn't work because of the different data types in the list.

Comment: @trizzou please add example where this post wouldn't work. This answer gives the correct result for your example list.

Comment: Basically I want all the values from ```mylist``` as one row of one big data frame in the end which holds all values from my ```biglist```. I don't know if it's clear what I mean.

Comment: @trizzou Please provide a like for like input and output. It is hard to understand what you want.